# what is Rating class? is it useful to get rating in playstore from the app itself?

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I have learnt about Rating class in android developers official docs. Here is the link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Rating.html

i am confusd that if this class is useful for rating an app in playstore within app? or internal widget like Rating bar? please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are not. Rating class is just a wrapper class which can be used to keep rating information, it implements Parcelable, hence, you can pass its instances between Android components (i.e Activity, Service...).

You can read the source code here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/media/java/android/media/Rating.java

Answer (score 0):

Unlike IOS, In android there is no official support for rating an app on playstore within the application itself. So the class you mentioned is used for collecting user input in terms of rating by the widget.